# Media query max-width not working inclusively

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm setting up the stylesheets for a responsive website, and want to provide different layouts for screens with width >= 768px and screens with width < 768px. However, when i use `@media (max-width: 767px)`, both the 767px and 768px are affected with the media query contents.

I've tried using `@media (max-width: 768px)` instead, but it (as expected) applied the media query contents to 768px, which is not the outcome i need.

You can try this code in any page (I tried it on Firefox and Chrome, with the same results):

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  body {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

I created a fiddle where you can see the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/e0hdyqc9/

When you add these rules to a page, both 767px and 768px are red. However, if you try replacing 767px by 768px, you'll find that now both 767px and 768px are green! How is that possible?

Comment: personally i would use 768px as my break point because it is also a bootstrap breakpoint. which can be seen here: https://bootstrapcreative.com/bootstrap-4-media-queries/ and I mean it is 1px difference I really don't think it will be the end of the world.

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future. I, too, had this annoying problem and I finally found out it was a Windows 10 issue, your scaling setting is probably set to 125% or higher, set it back to 100%, and then max-width media queries would work as expected (i.e. inclusively).

Comment: For me, the issue wasn't with 125% scaling in windows (which I continue to use). Instead, the issue was displaying my screen on my external monitor connected with my laptop (through hdmi if it matters). In that scenario, I would get the media queries being off by 1px. However, if I displayed my screen on my laptop monitor, that no longer happened and everything worked normally with the css media queries working exactly as they're supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the page header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Add this CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    body { background-color: green;  }}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
  body { background-color: yellow;}}
```

The red background will not show because of the min & max values!

When the `width=767px` is green & the `width=768px` is yellow, there won't be space for red.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your images didn't load for me, it looks like Imgur is down. However, it still isn't working for me. When the width=767px, the body is white! You can see it happening on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0hdyqc9/

Comment: Actually, it seems that this issue is only happening on my machine. I tried the fiddle on other machines and its working for them, so I'm accepting your answer as it is the correct, standards compliant solution. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future. I, too, had this annoying problem and I finally found out it was a Windows 10 issue, your scaling setting is probably set to 125% or higher, set it back to 100%, and then max-width media queries would work as expected (i.e. inclusively).

Comment: @Arad Can confirm this solution. Do you know why windows is affecting media queries?

Comment: @dude Glad it helped. But no, I don't exactly know WHY this problem exists, unfortunately.